# Hamiltonian vector fields for standard Poisson structure

Tags: differential-geometry, poisson-geometry

Given a Poisson manifold $(M,\Pi)$, a vector field $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ is called $\textit{Hamiltonian}$ if $\iota_X \Pi = df$ for some smooth $f$. A vector field $X$ that satisfies $\mathcal{L}_X\Pi=0$ is called $\textit{Poisson}$.

In general, Poisson vector fields need not be Hamiltonian. However, on $(\mathbb{R}^{2n}, \sum \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial y_i})$, every Poisson vector field is Hamiltonian. I wanted to prove this, however I can't seem to find how to begin. My first guess would be to use some analogous "Cartan magic formula", but I don't think this makes sense in the case of multi-vector fields (at least not immediately).

Any help is apprciated.

Comment: Do you know a bit about Poisson cohomology? The Poisson manifold that you mention is in fact symplectic, in which case the Poisson cohomology is isomorphic with the de Rham cohomology. Since the first de Rham cohomology group of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is zero, so is the first Poisson cohomology group. Therefore, all Poisson vector fields are Hamiltonian.

Comment: That makes sense! I'm still building towards Poisson cohomology, but I feel like making a bridge towards the symplectic counterpart really is the way to go, so I feel like your method is indeed the best one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A side note: you inverted the vector field $X$ and the 1-form $df$ in the definition of Hamiltonian vector field. $X$ is Hamiltonian if it is a Poisson gradient, and some equivalent notations are $X_{f} = \{f, \cdot\} = \pi(df, \cdot) = (df)^{\sharp} = \iota_{df}\pi $.

On a similar line, since you cannot feed vector fields to a bivector as you do with a 2-form, you cannot have a strict analogue of Cartan's magic formula for the Lie derivative of a bivector.

#### Back to your question

Page 122 and around there of

> Paulette Libermann and Charles-Michel Marle. Symplectic Geometry and
>   Analytical Mechanics

can be of help without invoking Poisson cohomology, that requires building Poisson calculus first (that is, defining brackets of 1-forms from usual Poisson brackets of smooth functions).

As @studiosus said, your Poisson manifold is special in two independent ways:

**A.** in $\mathbb{R}^n$ differential forms are closed iff exact (all de Rham cohomology groups are trivial); and

**B.** the Poisson bivector is non-degenerate everywhere (making the manifold symplectic).

These implications show how these two facts make any Poisson vector field a Hamiltonian vector field:

[image: Hamiltonian-Poisson-implications]

The arrows marked with (A) or (B) hold only if the respective condition holds; let's start climbing up this chain from the bottom.

A vector field $X$ is called *Poisson* if $\mathcal{L}_X \pi = 0$.

The first difficulty we face is that a degenerate bivector $\pi$ defines a non-bijective homomorphism $\sharp$ mapping a 1-form into a vector field, so for a generic vector field there may **not** exist a 1-form $\alpha$ such that $\alpha^{\sharp} = X$.

If a Poisson vector field belongs to the image of $\sharp$, so $\mathcal{L}_X \pi = 0$ and $X = \alpha^{\sharp}$ for some 1-form $\alpha$, we say that $X$ is *locally Hamiltonian*.

Proposition 10.5 at page 122 of Libermann's book shows that a vector field is locally Hamiltonian iff the related 1-form is *c-closed*, namely $d\alpha$ vanishes *on hamiltonian vector fields*.

Now, if **B.** holds, the Poisson bivector is non-degenerate, and it defines an *isomorphism* between vector fields and 1-forms: in particular every vector field is associated to precisely one 1-form [*** footnote**].

This means that, if **B.** holds, every Poisson vector field is locally hamiltonian, and it can be shown that every c-closed 1-form is closed (every vector can be written as the image of a Hamiltonian vector field at one point).

To summarize, if the Poisson bivector is non-degenerate, there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between Poisson vector fields and closed 1-forms.

Finally, as said in **A.**, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ a closed 1-form is exact: $\alpha = df$ for some function $f$; so the Poisson vector field we started with, $X = \alpha^{\sharp}$, is indeed Hamiltonian: $X = (df)^{\sharp}$.

---

[*** footnote**] If **B.** holds the Poisson manifold is symplectic. The symplectic form $\omega$ can be defined from the bivector since $\sharp^{-1}$ now makes sense; the non-degeneracy of $\pi$ grants the non-degeneracy of $\omega$; and interestingly the Jacobi property of the Poisson structure, or equivalently the vanishing Schouten brackets $[\pi,\pi]_S = 0$, assures that $d \omega = 0$.